# Is there a highcharts way to sequence series by serie types?

Tags: highcharts

We have two series that their series types are 'spline' and 'column'. I show them dynamical and if we get first serie type 'spline',column will block spline serie on the back side of graph. Is there a way that 'always show spline front side of column' ? here is the sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NN8H/

```
  series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            }
        },{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        },  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `series index` which allows to define order of series.

http://jsfiddle.net/4NN8H/2/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.index

Comment: And `series.zIndex`, [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.zIndex).

Answer (score 0):

Simply [`Array.sort()`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort&ei=QUTBUumnBqmk4gTAv4CYDA&usg=AFQjCNHhsnTi-QNulIOp5Xp29WT6GRduuw&sig2=03LgGi2nDABP8cNpJnRKKg&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bGE) them the way you want:

```
series = series.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.type > b.type) return 1;
    if (a.type < b.type) return -1;
});
```

This is just an easy sample. You can introduce your own, more sophisticated sort logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/4NN8H/1/